# discord run webhook from php

Tags: php, html, webhooks, discord

I have this question: I have a web page in php that with a request it write some data received into a MySql database:

I wish send also a bot with a webhook into a certain discord chat..

how can I pack and send the request to discord with the created webhook?

thanks in advance

Comment: Create a websocket event upon completion and make your bot catch it :)

Comment: thanks @Martijn.. but how can I do this? I looked in the `discord-api-docs` but I haven't found nothing useful ;)

Comment: I found this:

https://github.com/nopjmp/discord-webhooks

do exactly what I need!

hope it helps someother!